# how to use 2 function onload in html/php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi so I searched for an answer to this question but did not find one so this why I here.

i want to use 2 function on load in my PHP one function defines the opening message, and the other adds tags for the lightbox But I can not run the two together.

I tried from the PHP file to do:

```
<body onload="Lightbox.activate();set_message()">
```

And I tried from the js file to do:

```
function set_object(){
Lightbox.activate();
set_message();
};
//php file//
<body onload="set_object()">
```

Both options did not bring me success, but sometimes set_message() did work.
I'm wondering if it could be because Lightbox.activate() is supposed to add tags to the page but it does not know which page to add?
Is there a solution to run both at the same onload?.

-- Edit --

activate() function:

```
class Lightbox {
static activate() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
      <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="lightbox__inner">
              <button type="button" class="lightbox__close">
                  &times;
              </button>
              <div class="lightbox__content"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
   `);
  const lightBox = document.querySelector("#lightbox");
  const btnClose = lightBox.querySelector(".lightbox__close");
  const content = lightBox.querySelector(".lightbox__content");
  const nobtn = lightBox.querySelector(".no_action");
  const closeLightbox = () => {
      lightBox.style.display = "none";
      content.innerHTML = "";
  };  
  lightBox.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
      if (e.target.matches("#lightbox")) {
          closeLightbox();
      }
  });
  btnClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
      closeLightbox();
  });
  nobtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    closeLightbox();
  });
  } 

 static show(htmlOrElement) {
  const content = document.querySelector("#lightbox 
  .lightbox__content");

  document.querySelector("#lightbox").style.display = null;

  if (typeof htmlOrElement === "string") {
      content.innerHTML = htmlOrElement;
  } else {
      content.innerHTML = "";
      content.appendChild(htmlOrElement);
  }
 }
 }
```

set_message() function:

```
function set_message(){

var day = new Date();

var hr = day.getHours();

var mesg = document.getElementById('hello');
var name = mesg.textContent;

if( hr >= 1 || hr <= 5){
  mesg.innerHTML = "Good night";

}
else if( hr >= 6 || hr <=11){
  mesg.innerHTML = "Good morning";
}
else if( hr >= 12 || hr <=16){
  mesg.innerHTML = "Good afternoon";
}
else if( hr >= 17 || hr <= 00){

  mesg.innerHTML = "Good evening";
}
mesg.innerHTML += name;

}
```

Comment: It should work. You can put any JavaScript in `onXXX` attributes, and that can be multiple statements separated by `;`.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Barmar i did separated by ; and i dont see error on console

Comment: The problem must be in the functions. There's no reason why it wouldn't call them.

Comment: Do you also have an assignment to `window.onload` in a `<script>` block? That will replace `<body onload>`

Comment: @Barmar the <script> tag only use src for the js file

Comment: @Barmar I add the function bc you say maybe it's a problem with the function..

Comment: @AvivMoyal it's not a good way to attach event listeners to the elements. You can create inline `<script>` tag with the [`window.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method, where you call everything else.

Comment: @koloml Is that really the problem?
Because activate() function just don't work If I try to run both functions onload

Comment: It should work either way, it's just better style to use addEventListener. You can add multiple listeners without overriding each other.

Comment: It works if you only call one function in the body onload?